# how can we change the position of pop up?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using google customer reviews script it showing a popup on my website corner bottom right but I want to change its position from right to left because my live chat is there but it's not working through CSS how to do it my code is

window.renderBadge = function() {
    var ratingBadgeContainer = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(ratingBadgeContainer);
    window.gapi.load('ratingbadge', function() {
      window.gapi.ratingbadge.render(ratingBadgeContainer, {"merchant_id": 7912975});
    });
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the position from the **Merchant Center account**. Login to your account go to **Merchant Center programs**. After go to **Design > Layouts**. Click on you block an you should have position.[image]

You can see more details [here](https://www.simtechdev.com/docs/addons/google-customer-reviews/index.html).

Comment: it will be applicable for  all pages??

Comment: that changes the position of the review block. Technically it should be like that for all pages.